# How to embed Telegram chat views in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, telegram

I am building an Ionic application and want to integrate Telegram's web client(Webogram) into my application.
Currently I am redirecting from my ionic application to webogram using:

```
window.location.href ="signin.html#/";
```

Now I want to embed the view of webogram chat into a div in my view.
Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Webogram link : https://github.com/zhukov/webogram

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way is inserting an IFRAME tag inside the DIV tag that you want to display the desired web page.

```
<DIV class="..." id="..." style="...">
<IFRAME src="..."></IFRAME>
</DIV>
```

Comment: I think this is not an option because then my controller will not be able to interact with the IFrame

Comment: You can interact with the page in the `IFRAME` tag with `window.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow` .
that myIframe is the id of `IFRAME` tag.